# SHA256 creates a unique hash for two *.wim that have identical content - are there better methods for verifying *.wim contents?

Tags: sha-256, integrity

I'm trying to verify that the contents of a Windows Image are identical for two WIM files; however, I think the timestamps for the file modifications are affecting the final checksums--even though the contents of the archives are identical.

Are there other methods to verify that the contents are identical?

At the moment I am using (Get-FileHash -Path *IMAGE*.wim).hash to find the SHA256 value.

Would a query for image content, and then a comparison of the results, be adequate? The problem with this method is that it doesn't check file size.

```
Get-WindowsImageContent -ImagePath *IMAGE*.wim -Index 1 | Out-File ImageHash.txt | Get-FileHash -Path ImageHash.txt
```

Comment: Hashes generally don't care about metadata...

Comment: there's what I thought. git file diff does what I need but I cant use that for the wim. maybe the file order is changing.. or codepage is changing for something in my environment